# Calculating sin over a column with missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with columns of 2 geo locations (long_1, lat_1, long_2, lat_2) and I want to add a column for the distance between them. The approximated formula can be found in the internet, ignore the details, it involves sin and cos and that's where my problem is.

I want to calculate `np.sin( df["long_1"] )`. It works if all values are not null but once I have missing values it throws an error instead of returning `NaN`. I get the following error:

```
In [97]: np.sin( df["long_1"] )
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-d95dd98ecd44> in <module>()
----> 1 np.sin( df["long_1"] )

AttributeError: sin
```

Any idea what might be the problem? Or if I'm wrong here - what's the best way to calculate sin/cos over a Series with some missing values (expected behaviour should be to return `NaN` when the input value is missing).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with NumPy's "masked arrays"?

Comment: Do you mean this: np.sin(df["long_1"][ df["long_1"].notnull() ] )  ? Still gives the same..

Comment: No, that is "fancy indexing."  Look up "masked arrays" and you'll see what I mean...but I am not sure it will help you--just something to poke around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like your dtype is object meaning numpy tries to call an attribute `sin` on each of the elements of the array. Typing it as float should work.

e.g.

```
df["long_1"] = df["long_1"].astype(np.float64)
```

or

```
np.sin(df["long_1"].astype(np.float64))
```

HTH,
Dave

Comment: This is a long-standing [issue in numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/1611). Mathematical functions on arrays of object type return the unhelpful ``AttributeError``.